# Hash Tables or BST?

Tags: c, hashtable, binary-search-tree

Currently i have a problem that i'm trying to figure out but not sure if my answers are correct.

You have 1 million records. In these records you will frequently need to search by
two criteria: employee ID and salary (but not by both at the same time).
You have the following constraints:

> - each record is very large and because of that you can only keep one copy of this data.
> - Your program needs to be reasonably fast. Simply scanning through all the items for each search would be too slow.

What data structure would you use?

My Answer?

I would use Hash table because the worst case time would be O(1000000) = O(1)

> How will you retrieve the record when you search by ID?
>
> How will you retrieve the record when you search by salary?

Comment: Will you ever need to search by salary range?  (e.g. "show me all salaries between $20,000 and $25,000" or similar?)  If so, you'd need to scan through the entire hash table (O(N)) to do it, since the hash table's O(1) lookups only work if you know the exact key value(s) you are looking for...

Comment: "Use a hash table" is just the start of the answer. How are you going to search on two keys with only one copy of the data? I think this is what the question is trying to probe about your knowledge. The choice between tree and hash table is secondary, and you might use both. Think about missing details. Will you have to search by a range of salaries - which is realistic - or a particular dollar value - not so useful? The difference matters.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner well for the ID i would know the exact location is i sort the IDs first then use hash? but for the salary you have a point....

Comment: @Gene i think in this case its actually by a particular dollar value. I said hash because if i have a million records it would be easier to sort and hash them so the IDs would require a O(1) time but for the salaries i'm stuck because i would only have one copy.

Comment: @BassamMetwally If I understand correctly, it seems unlikely that you could use a hash table for the salaries because it's realistic to assume that more than one employee could have the same value, which would cause collisions when trying to hash the keys (unless there's some guarantee that salaries are also unique?) Also, are you allowed to have references to the records, or must the actual record objects be stored in the data structures?

Comment: @ray the above data is all there is. So i'm assuming no they will not be unique.

Comment: @ray but it does say you cannot search for both at the same time. so if we're looking for a salary it would probably be just one unique right? otherwise we might end up with 1000 different employees

Comment: @BassamMetwally My interpretation of the phrase "cannot search for both at the same time" is that you're not prohibited from searching for one or the other in different attempts, which would allow me to search for ID on my 1st attempt and based on salary on my 2nd. If you key your hash table with IDs (and values as refs to records) you can also build a tree to arrange records based on salaries (with node contents being refs to records) and you preserve your one-record-only requirement. Does that sound like it would work for you?

Comment: @ray yeah i believe that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect many collision issues for a hash-table based on salary, but one for an ID could work with no collisions quite easily using a little cryptographic theory. It seems odd to want to *search* by salary rather than sort or get some range, which could be performed much more easily on a BST.

The short of it though is that if you want to search by two independent properties you're going to have to maintain two structures. Fortunately pointers exist, so you don't have to keep multiple copies. Personally I'd keep a hash table of IDs to references, then a BST of salaries to references, but if I'm restricted to one datatype I'd have to do a BST with nodes like this:

```
    Node {
        int id;
        Node idLessThan;
        Node idGreaterThan;

        int salary;
        Node salaryLessThan;
        Node salaryGreaterThan;

        Data fileInfo;
    }
```

Creating essentially two BSTs over the same node set.

Comment: I was commenting thinking the same thing. But what if salaries are unique? would a hash table be better?

Comment: If you only want to search by salary and not sort by salary it'd be more efficient in both memory and access time. Any situation I can think of in which you'd want to only be able to search by exact salary is pretty contrived.

Comment: So if i search only it would be efficient to use BST. I understand but i its a question to test our understanding of the concepts.

Comment: Exact search is more efficient as a Hash Table, but in a BST finding all salaries greater than x is as simple as finding x and returning all children of the `salaryGreaterThan` node (Slightly complicated by the fact that x may not be in the table, but still much more efficient than having to check the hash for each value between $20,000 and $25000 for a hash table)

Comment: If you wanted to use salaries as the key in your hash table, and also support the case where several people have the same salary, you could do so by making the values of the hash table be of type list-of-people rather than type person.  Then when adding a person to the table you'd check to see if his salary already exists as a key; if it does, add the person to the end of the list associated with that salary; if it doesn't, insert a new list with that key and just the one person in the list.